# Is [@{$myArray}] equivalent to $myArray in Perl if I'm not mutating the values?

Tags: perl

I've got some Perl code:

```
{
  key => [@{$myArray}]
}
```

And I'd like to refactor that to:

```
{
  key => $myArray
}
```

Are the two semantically equivalent if I'm not mutating the value pointed to by `key`?

Comment: yes, those arrays will have the same *contents* but their memory addresses will be different

Comment: @HunterMcMillen sounds like a good answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They behave differently when

1. `@{ $h->{key} }` is changed. (The difference you mentioned)
2. `@$array` is changed.
3. `$array` isn't dereferenceable as an array (e.g. `$array` is a string).
4. `$array` is an object that overloads `@{}`.
5. the elements of `@$array` are large or magical.

   The first snippet makes a copy of the elements when the hash is created, so it will be slower, and it will use more memory. Any magical aspects of the array or elements (e.g. if the array is a `:shared` array, or an array tied to `Tie::File`) will not be copied by the second snippet.

Comment: Good point about magic.  It would also affect tied and overloaded objects.

Comment: @Schwern, Only the few overloaded objects that overload `=`. Copying doesn't stringify.

Comment: I was thinking of `@{}` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Schwern, Ah yes, that too. I'll add it.

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not.  Even if the array referenced by `$data->{key}` is never altered.

`$myArray` is a reference to the array.  `[@{$myArray}]` makes a copy of the array referenced by $myArray and then takes a reference to that.  Copying the array works both ways.  It shields `$myArray` from changes made by `$data` but it also shields `$data` from changes in `$myArray`.
Even if you don't mutate `$data->{key}` they still have semantic differences.  For example...

```
my $myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
$data->{key1} = $myArray;
$data->{key2} = [@{$myArray}];
$myArray->[1] = "q";

print $data->{key1}[1];  # q
print $data->{key2}[1];  # b
```

Unless you fully control `$myArray` and `$data`, that refactoring is unsafe.

Comment: this is also unsafe if i don't control `$data`, correct?

Comment: @aaronstacy Yes.  You stated that you do so I didn't cover it.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by *“Even if `key` is never altered”*. Hash keys cannot be altered.

Comment: @Borodin I used the OP's terminology.  So long as the array referenced by `$data->{key}` is not changed.

Answer (score 2):

It would create a different reference to an array with the same content. This would be functionally equivalent in the case where the array is never changed, but if someone comes along later and does something like this:

```
push @{ $p->{key} }, "foo";
```

Then in the former case, it would leave `$myArray` untouched. In the latter, it would change the values everywhere else `$myArray` is used. If you absolutely don't want the original to be mutated by any future changes, then your proposed refactoring may be detrimental.

Comment: He specifically asked for differences other than the one you mentioned.